# PHP Check if all characters in a string are Chinese

Tags: php, string

I'm currently using this method of detecting whether any chinese characters exist within a string

```
if (preg_match("/\p{Han}+/u", $str))
{
  //made in china
}
```

Works fine but I also need to run a check to see if the full string is chinese, not just a check for any characters being chinese. I can't seem to figure out how to do this, can it be done with preg match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `^` and `$` qualifiers:

```
if (preg_match("/^\p{Han}+$/u", $str))
{
  //made in china
}
```

Comment: He just want to detect if the string includes chinese rather than if the whole string is chinese or not, will that work?

Comment: So OP has sample for what you've mentioned in his code. And he's asking how to check if entire string is in chinese. That is - if any symbol from start to end is chinese, whole string is chinese

Comment: Dp yes you're right, missed the second paragraph of his question.